# Do you know if can i connect to appharbor on FTP?

Tags: ftp, appharbor

I have two web application on appharbor cloud, when i make upload from one i want to update the second web aplication with uploaded documents and i did this before on FTP, do i have this possibilities to copy files on FTP in AppHarbor cloud ?